# Get the number between two special characters in bash

Tags: regex, bash, buildkite

I have a string that is actually a buildkite commit message and I am trying to retrieve a number (pull request number) between two special characters.

E.g. the string could be something like

```
"some commit message (#36)

* test

* unsquashed

* etc

* bla"
```

Using bash, now I want to get the number 36 from the above string. Unfortunately I will not be able to use `sed` or `grep` with `perl-regexp`.

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Could the text also be something like _foo (#15) bar (#17)_?

Comment: @user1934428 No I'd assume not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the parameter expansion operators.

```
commit_msg="some commit message (#36)
* test
* unsquashed
* etc
* bla"
id=${commit_msg#*(#} # remove everything up to (#
id=${id%%)*} # remove everything starting from )
echo "$id"
```